# Проверить, активно ли окно, добавить классы

Tags: html, jquery, css

Лирика: на некоторых сайтах, к примеру YouTube, есть что-то вроде чекера окна/вкладки на активность, то есть на том же ютубе видео не начнет воспроизводиться, пока пользователь не перейдет на эту вкладку. Так вот, нужен скрипт для прелоадера на сайте. Примерный код ниже. Суть: проверить, является ли окно активным, то есть, видит ли пользователь сейчас сайт, если да - добавить к `preload-container` класс `visible`. Затем проверить, загрузилась ли страница, да - убрать `visible` и добавить `loaded`.

[Кодперо](http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/qZpLgV)

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.preload-container .block-left, .preload-container .block-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #add;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 6s ease;
}
.preload-container .block-left {
  left: 0;
}
.preload-container.loaded .block-left {
  left: -5000px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.preload-container .block-right {
  right: 0;
}

.preload-container.loaded .block-right {
  right: -5000px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.preload-container .block-center {
  height: 0;  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  background: #6AA;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 1.5px);
  z-index: 9;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.preload-container.loaded .block-center {
  display: none;
}
.preload-container.visible .block-center {
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.preload-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #add;
  color: #277;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #6aa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.preload-content p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font: 30px/100px sans-serif;
}

.preload-container.loaded .preload-content {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="preload-container visible">
    <div class="block-left"></div>
    <div class="block-center"></div>
    <div class="block-right"></div>
  <div class="preload-content">
  <p>site logo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пользователь который перешел точнее кликнул на вкладку и пользователь который "видит" сайт это разные вещи. Уточните при каком именно условии нужно добавить класс visible?

Comment: @stckvrw перешел

Comment: window.blur window.focus не оно?

Comment: @Jean-Claude дело в том, что  я абсолютно не умею писать скрипты..

Answer (score 1):

Как то так:

```
var preloader = document.getElementById('preloader'),
        pageLoaded = false;

window.onblur = function() {
    if (!pageLoaded) preloader.className = 'preloader-container';
};

window.onfocus = function() {
    if (!pageLoaded) preloader.className = 'preloader-container visible';
};

window.onload = function(){
    preloader.className = 'preloader-container loaded';
  pageLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: добавил нужный id к диву, в песочнице все работает, на "живой" странице - нет, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null`

Comment: http://malginovdesign.ru/test/test.html